# How can I correctly get this component to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component defined, Pragmatometer, which I am trying to render to div#main:

```
        React.render(React.createElement(Pragmatometer,
          {}), document.getElementById('main'));
```

Chrome's JavaScript console shows, with line numbers in the thousands for ReactJS:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pragmatometer</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
            {
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pragmatometer</h1>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.js">
    </script>
    <script
      src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/0.3.1/showdown.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src="/js/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is the error in that React.render() call, or an issue concerning the Pragmatometer component? What are the usual suspects for this kind of issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Just an idea .. move the script files to the <head> section of the document?

Comment: Have you set up the Pragmatometer component ? and why don't you use the jsx syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rendering is now done via ReactDOM.render()

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement('Pragmatometer',
        null, 'Hello'),
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
React.render(
      React.createElement('Pragmatometer',
          null, 'Hello'),
        document.getElementById('main')
      );
```

if you want to use Pragmatometer without single quote '' you should set it up abd I'm wondering why you don't use jsx it's very easy to write the component.